# Script alternative to nested IF statements Google Sheets, ignore text cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to do a weighted average of integer scores. I have 4 values in score array {Manager, Colleague1, Colleague2, Colleague3} with corresponding weights {50%,  16.67%, 16.67%, 16.67%}. I need an alternative to nested IF statements (along the lines of an *else IF* code in Scripts) to control for possible "NA" value in cell, ignoring the cell and adjusting the weight array accordingly. (Manager must always be 50%, if manager = NA then unweighted average).

Additional complication: each value in score array is in a separate tab/sheet of the doc.

So basically I need weighted average with standard weights, but if cell = text then weighted average with adjusted weights.

Anyone have a solution?

Comment: It would be easier if you show an example of input and desired output. Sorry, probably I'm a visual learner since I barely can understand your goal. How it should look like?

Comment: Here is a sample sheet created specifically to answer this question. Paste some sample data there and people will be more likely to be able to help.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1egCDDqUGhX3r-mA8t9TfUDH_cqxxulqooZvwY3eaPGY/edit